# How to Test Window Click Event Listener in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I hope this is a simple question.

I have a select-box directive that should close when anything is clicked outside of the directive. So the window has a an event listener to hide the box once a click event is heard-

```
$window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  $scope.expanded = false;
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Which works fine, no complaints. But I'm trying to write a unit test for this and can't figure out how to trigger the click even on the **window** itself.

```
it('should close the dropdown if the window is clicked', function() {
  toggleButton.trigger('click');

  expect(eleSimpleOptionBox.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(false);

  $window.trigger('click');

  expect(eleSimpleOptionBox.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);
});
```

I've tried the following-

```
$window.trigger('click'); // as well as .click()
$window.triggerHandler('click');
angular.element('body').trigger('click'); // as well as .click()
someWrappingElement.trigger('click'); // as well as .click()
```

Comment: do you call `$digest` on your scope or `$rootScope` after triggering the event?

Comment: Neither. But in the test the first click trigger works without a `$digest` so I assume the second would. It's using the DOMs event listeners and not angulars event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar situation trying to test a click event on the $window object. I tried all of the above to try and trigger the event but I couldn't get the event to fire. My workaround was to-do something like the code snippet below in the test so that I could test the listener function.. Still not happy with it, but it's better that no test I guess...

```
describe('test $window events', ()=> {
   var callbackFn; //variable to capture the callback

    beforeEach(()=> {
        //spy on the addEventListener method and capture the function reference
        spyOn($window, 'addEventListener').and.callFake((event: string, callback: any) => { 
            callbackFn = callback; 
        });
    });

    //trigger the callbackFn in your test
    it('should call the event listener', ()=> {
       callback(); //this will trigger the event.. 
       expect(true).toBe(true);
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType, x, y) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent(
        eventType,                  // type
        true,                       // canBubble
        eventType != 'mousemove',   // cancelable
        window,                     // view
        0,                          // detail
        x,                          // screenX
        y,                          // screenY
        x,                          // clientX
        y);                         // clientY
    node.dispatchEvent(event);
}
triggerMouseEvent($window, 'click');
```

The [initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) function is deprecated now and [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) should be used, but looks like IE doesn't support MouseEvent yet.